# Persist detailed information about failed Item processing

Tags: kotlin, spring-batch

I´ve got a Job that runs a TaskletStep, then a chunk-based step and then another TaskletStep.
In each of these steps, errors (in the form of Exceptions) can occur.

The chunk-based step looks like this:

```
stepBuilderFactory
            .get("step2")
            .chunk<SomeItem, SomeItem>(1)
            .reader(flatFileItemReader)
            .processor(itemProcessor)
            .writer {}
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy { _ , _ -> true } // skip all Exceptions and continue
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .throttleLimit(taskExecutor.corePoolSize)
            .build()
```

The whole job definition:

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
            .validator(validator())
            .preventRestart()
            .start(taskletStep1)
            .next(step2)
            .next(taskletStep2)
            .build()
```

I expected that Spring Batch somehow picks up the Exceptions that occur along the way, so I can then create a Report including them after the Job has finished processing. Looking at the different contexts, there´s also fields that should contain `failureExceptions`. However, it seems there´s no such information (especially for the chunked step).

What would be a good approach if I need information about:

- what Exceptions did occur in which Job execution
- which Item was the one that triggered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobExecution` provides a method to [get all failure exceptions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecution.html#getAllFailureExceptions--) that happened during the job. You can use that in a `JobExecutionListener#afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution)` to generate your report.

In regards to which items caused the issue, this will depend on where the exception happens (during the read, process or write operation). For this requirement, you can use one of the `ItemReadListener`, `ItemProcessListener` or `ItemWriteListener` to keep record of the those items (For example, by adding them to the job execution context to be able to get access to them in the `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` method for your report).

Comment: I´m exactly using this `getAllFailureExceptions` and it´s always empty for me. Is it maybe an interference with my skipping of all Exceptions?

Comment: Oh, another question: are the Exceptions not persisted anywhere? So that means I´ve got access in `afterJob()` but then never again some time later?

Comment: Have you tried another skip policy? I don't see the added value of skipping everything without a limit (what if something is fundamentally wrong with the input and all items are skipped?). Failure exceptions are not persisted, that's why the listener approach is appropriate IMO to generate the report (or to persist these failures somewhere for later use within the listener).

Comment: Ok, I think I found a workable solution. I had to implement a `SkipListener` that adds the Exceptions to the `StepExecution` (via `addFailureException`) when a skip is happening and then persist them in the `JobExecutionListener.afterJob`.

Comment: Indeed, that's the idea. I only mentioned Item read/process/write listeners but a skip listener is also what you might need if you are interested in skippable exceptions. If the answer helped, please accept it.